# PHP display content based on day and timeframe

Tags: php, wordpress, date, time

I need to display the ON AIR CONTENT every Friday at 9pm and then stop at 12am and revert back to the OFF AIR CONTENT.

Below are the 2 sets of code that I manually change to make this possible. If I get the right code I can automate this.

Can anyone help me?

```
/* ON AIR CONTENT*/

    function banner_rotator() {
    if (is_home()) { ?>
    <div id="rotator"><iframe width="630" height="386" src="http://www.ustream.tv/embed/8805257?v=3&amp;wmode=direct?autoplay=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: 0px none transparent;"> </iframe> <?php if(function_exists('vslider')){ vslider('frontpage'); } ?></div>
    <div class="main">
                <!-- FIFTH EXAMPLE -->
                <div class="view view-fifth">
                    <img src="../1.jpg" />
                    <div class="mask">
                        <h2>FULLY LOADED 2012</h2>
                        <p>This event has been cancelled.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="info">Details</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="view view-fifth">
                    <img src="../2.jpg" />
                    <div class="mask">
                        <h2>KAFINAL - FALLING IN LOVE</h2>
                        <p>"The feedback to Falling in Love has been tremendous all over. I am getting calls from people in Jamaica, the Caribbean and even in the States...</p>
                        <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>  
 </div>
<?php }
}

    add_action('thesis_hook_before_content', 'banner_rotator');

    _____________________________________________________________________________________

    /* OFF AIR CONTENT */


    function banner_rotator() {
    if (is_home()) { ?>
    <div id="rotator"> <?php if(function_exists('vslider')){ vslider('frontpage'); } ?></div>
    <div class="main">
                <!-- FIFTH EXAMPLE -->
                <div class="view view-fifth">
                    <img src="../1.jpg" alt="FULLY LOADED 2012" title="FULLY LOADED 2012" />
                    <div class="mask">
                        <h2>FULLY LOADED 2012</h2>
                        <p>This event has been cancelled.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="info">Details</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="view view-fifth">
                    <img src="../2.jpg" alt="KAFINAL - FALLING IN LOVE" title="FULLY LOADED 2012" />
                    <div class="mask">
                        <h2>KAFINAL - FALLING IN LOVE</h2>
                        <p>"The feedback to Falling in Love has been tremendous all over. I am getting calls from people in Jamaica, the Caribbean and even in the States...</p>
                        <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>  
 </div>
<?php }
}

    add_action('thesis_hook_before_content', 'banner_rotator');
```

Comment: What is it that doesn't work?....

Comment: Right now I manually switch between the on air code and the off air code above. I need to right a PHP date function that will automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP date("G") function will give you the time in 24 hour format as a string.  You may then test that and make whatever decisions you would like.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. Can you help?